# Is there a way to have a <div> grid space vertically and horizontally aligned, while taking up the whole area?

Tags: html, css

I need to have a grid be centered while taking up the whole area.

the code I have currently:

```css
//CSS
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10,auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10,10%);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
}

.scramble {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1 / span 10;
}

.timer {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 30;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 2 / span 7;
  grid-row: 3 / span 4;
}

.times {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  font-size: 30;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 9 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / span 9
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="scramble">...</div>
  <div class="timer" id="time">1</div>
  <div class="times">1</div>
</div>
```

As I said, I need it to be centered both vertically and horizontally while taking up the full box.

Edit: also if it wasn't apparent I'm making a Rubik's Cube scramble generator and timer.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert on grid layout, but since no one is answering, I'll give it a try. The only way to make it cover 100% height seems to be to put `<div class="grid-container">` inside a `div` and then give `.grid-container` `position: absolute`.

Also, you forgot semicolons at the end of `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` for `.grid-container`.

To make it the entire width you need to turn off `justify-content` too. Also what do you mean by centering? If you make it a 10 by 10 grid, then the center is between the middle 2 cells, and not inside any grid cell. And if something takes up an entire area, then it is centered by default?

My 2 cents.

Comment: I want the text to be centered in the middle of the grid box, while having the grid take up the grid boxes entire area.

Comment: Im not sure I understand you. The grid has grid boxes in them. You want text centered in the grid boxes or in the center of the grid? Isn't the former  already what is happening? You have added `text-align: center;` to the grid boxes, which makes the text centered in them. Also, what do you mean by 'taking up the full box', which element do you want to have take up the full box, the `.grid-container`?